# How to get max cpu useage of a pod in kubernetes over a time interval (say 30 days) in promql?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql, prometheus-operator

I am trying to estimate the resource (cpu) request and limit values, for which I want to know the max cpu usage of a pod in last one month using prometheus.

I checked this question but couldn't get what i want [Generating range vectors from return values in Prometheus queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717605/generating-range-vectors-from-return-values-in-prometheus-queries)

I tried this but it seems max_over_time doesn't worker over rate

```
max (  
  max_over_time(
    rate(
      container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m]
    )[30d]
  )
) by (pod_name)
```

invalid parameter 'query': parse error at char 64: range specification must be preceded by a metric selector, but follows a *promql.Call instead

Comment: What is your prometheus version?

Answer (score 6):

You'd need to capture the inner expression (rate of container cpu usage) as a [recording rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/rules/):

```
- record: container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:rate5m
  expr: rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m])
```

then use this new timeseries to calculate max_over_time:

```
max (  
  max_over_time(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:rate5m[30d])
) by (pod_name)
```

This is only need in Prometheus versions older to 2.7 as [subqueries can be calculated on the fly](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/#subquery), see [this blog post for more details](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/).

*Bear in mind though*, if you're planning to use this composite query (max of  max_per_time of data collected in the last 30 days) for alerting or visualisation (rather than an one-off query), then you'd *still want to use the recording rule* to improve the query's performance. Its the classic CS computational complexity tradeoff (memory/storage space required for storing the recording rule as a separate timeseries vs. the computational resources needed to process data for 30 days!)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try something like this:

`max_over_time(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="pod-name-here-759b8f",container_name!="POD", container_name!=""}[1m])) [720h:1s])`